# Jquery $(:text) and $(input[type="text"])

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any difference between `$(:text)` and `$(input[type="text"])` **Jquery** selector.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/

Comment: Why don't you read the docs?

Comment: May be you can find your answer here. https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.5.2, :text selects input elements that have no specified type attribute (in which case type="text" is implied).

This difference in behavior between $( ":text" ) and $( "[type=text]" ), can be seen below:

```
$( "<input>" ).is( "[type=text]" ); // false
$( "<input>" ).is( ":text" ); // true
```

Additional Notes:

Because :text is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :text cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="text"] instead.
https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/

Answer (score 0):

From the Jquery [api](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/):

> $( ":text" ) is equivalent to $( "*:text" ).

so equivalent of `$('input[type="text"]')` is  `$("input:text")`

Comment: "so equivalent of $('input[type="text"]') is  $("input:text")" - No, it's not. When you provide a link to the docs you should be familiar with its contents.

Answer (score 0):

`$(input[type="text"])` will select all the input tags which have the type specified

`$(:text)` will select all the input tags which have the type specified or not defined

`<input type="text" name="text1" value="abc" />`

`<input name="text2" value="xyz" />`

`$(input[type="text"])` will select the first input tag only

`$(:text)` will select both input tages

check [js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/7XjQx/)